# Which Label is clicked on PyQT

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt5

I have several labels displaying images. These labels are added to `self.lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)` . I get which images to display with date_time from database and display images in this manner.

```
if rows2 != None:
   for row in rows2:
      pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("../"+row[1]).scaled(QtCore.QSize(200, 200)
                              , QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
      if not pixmap.isNull():
         self.date_time.append(row[2])
         self.count += 1
         label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
         label.setPixmap(pixmap)
         label.mousePressEvent = self.showInfo
         self.lay.addWidget(label)
```

```
+------+-----------------------------+---------------------+
| p_id | image_path                  | date_time           |
+------+-----------------------------+---------------------+
|    0 | transfered_images/0/027.jpg | 2020-09-14 17:12:46 |
|    2 | transfered_images/2/227.jpg | 2020-09-15 09:44:38 |
+------+-----------------------------+---------------------+
```

When clicked `showInfo` is called

```
def showInfo(self,event):
   print(self.date_time[self.count-1])
```

But this way only last image's date_time is displayed 
How to identify which label was clicked and display time accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably reimplement the QLabel class, and make a variable inside that can hold the date_time. This way you also keep the native functionality of the `mousePressEvent`.

```
class MyLabel(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    def __init__(self, text='', parent=None, date_time=None):
        super().__init__(text, parent)
        self.date_time = date_time
    
    def mousePressEvent(self, ev):
        super().mousePressEvent(ev)
        print(self.date_time)
```

and use it like

```
label = MyLabel(date_time=row[2])
```

EDIT:

The inside of your loop would look like.

```
      if not pixmap.isNull():
         label = MyLabel(date_time=row[2])
         label.setPixmap(pixmap)
         self.lay.addWidget(label)
```

Comment: Can you please also mention what should I write instead of ```label.mousePressEvent = self.showInfo``` . I wrote it as ```label.mousePressEvent``` . It gives the result as expected but I don't think that it's the right way

Comment: See edit. The mousePressEvent function is run natively when the label is pressed.